# KotlinJS + Typescript: Atomicfu TraceBase reference not found in d.ts file

Tags: typescript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

With either `coroutine` or `ktor` dependency, when `KotlinJS` npm library is published, in the resulting generated typescript `d.ts` file there are `atomicfu` references

```
export namespace kotlinx.atomicfu {
    function atomic$ref$<T>(initial: T, trace: kotlinx.atomicfu.TraceBase): kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicRef<T>;
    function atomic$boolean$(initial: boolean, trace: kotlinx.atomicfu.TraceBase): kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicBoolean;
    function atomic$int$(initial: number, trace: kotlinx.atomicfu.TraceBase): kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicInt;
    function atomic$long$(initial: kotlin.Long, trace: kotlinx.atomicfu.TraceBase): kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicLong;
}
```

but reference for `TraceBase` is missing from the file and when compiling a `Typescript` app that depends on above `kotlinJS` library, it complains about missing `TraceBase`.

The only way to move forward is to add `skipLibCheck = true` in the `tsconfig` file. That's not an ideal solution for user of the library.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known compiler bug. There is an issue created to fix it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50464

Temporarily you can solve it using Gradle by removing all `atomicfu` references from the generated `d.ts` file.

Solution below assumes that you use [this Gradle plugin NPM package publishing](https://github.com/mpetuska/npm-publish). It provides a `packJsNpmPublication` task that builds the `js` library publication code with specific naming for generated files.

You should add below two gradle tasks

```kotlin
// This task copies content of "js" build folder into a "temp" folder

tasks.register<Copy>("copyJsBuildContentToTemp") {
    this.from("$buildDir/publications/npm/js/")
    this.into("$buildDir/publications/npm/js/temp/")
}

// This task goes through your `d.ts` file from `temp` folder,
// Removes all the lines containing `atomicfu` word and then last line with '}'
// Then copies the modified file back into `js` folder that replaces the original file
// At the end, it deletes the `temp` folder

tasks.register<Copy>("removeAtomicFu") {
    var atomicfu = false
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    from(buildDir.resolve("$buildDir/publications/npm/js/temp/${rootProject.name}-${project.name}.d.ts")) {
        filter {
            when {
                it.contains("atomicfu") -> {
                    atomicfu = true
                    ""
                }
                atomicfu && it == "}" -> {
                    atomicfu = false
                    ""
                }
                else -> it
            }
        }
    }
    this.into("$buildDir/publications/npm/js/")
    dependsOn("copyJsBuildContentToTemp")
    doLast {
        delete("$buildDir/publications/npm/js/temp")
    }
}

// This makes sure that `removeAtomicFu` tasks runs at the end of task 
// `assembleJsNpmPublication` so when `pack` or `publish` runs and creates 
// the `tarball` file, it would put update content in the `tgz` file
project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.findByName("assembleJsNpmPublication")?.finalizedBy("removeAtomicFu")
}
```

Now if you run `./gradlew packJsNpmPublication` you'll have build content without `atomicfu` references.